# Gradlew can not find aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-cli, java-11, gradlew

I am using the following command in gralew to use the aws code artifact locally.

```
"aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain myComany --domain-owner 49XXXXXXXXXX --query authorizationToken --output text"
```

I have Java 11 and 17 from openjdk. For the java 17 projects with gradlew 7.4.2 its working. But java 11 project with gradlew 6.3, I get following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aws": error=2, No such file or directory
```

aws cli is working fine from terminal and JAVA_HOME is set to 11.
I am using a mac with m1 chip and Ventura 13.4.1

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the Gradle of versions 6.X and earlier doesn't use global $PATH. More details you can find in this [response](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/exec-execute-in-gradle-doesnt-use-path/25598). You can use custom gradle property inside `gradle.properties` file, like `aws.cli.path=/usr/local/bin/aws` and then use it in your `build.gradle` as `def awscli = project.property("aws.cli.path")`.

This is working example from our legacy project with Gradle 6.3, tested on Mac with m1 chip:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://accountAlias-1234567890.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/repositoryName/'
        credentials {
            username "aws"
            def awsProfile = project.property("aws.profile")
            def awscli = project.property("aws.cli.path")
            def base = "$awscli codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain domainname --domain-owner 1234567890 --region us-east-1 --query authorizationToken --output text"
            def command = awsProfile ? "$base --profile $awsProfile" : base
            def process = command.execute()
            process.waitFor()
            def token = process.text.trim()
            password token
        }
    }
}
```